# Android Sherlock ActionBar OnCreateOption

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to add a next button in my app action bar ( Sherlock ), I'm new and couldn't find tut's anywhere so I tried using guides from Android.com, I want to add a next button into my first activity action  bar

this is my Code at the StartActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.StartActivity, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and this is the xml of main.xml

```
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/bNext"
          android:title="Next"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    </menu>
```

I get an error from R."menu".StartActivity

```
menu cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First go into your menu folder and and add an .xml file which looks like this :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <item 
          android:id="@+id/share"
          android:title="Share"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:icon="@drawable/actionbar_share" />

   </menu>
```

Then you go into your activity where you are calling the action bar and do this :

```
      @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
     {
          MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
          return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     }
```

where action_bar is the xml file you created in the first step
Then after you get your button in your action bar you need to add the

```
         public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

method and add whatever code you want there to be

Comment: I need to add the folder called menu ? ( new info :D )

Comment: I get this when I add onOptionsItemSelected " Cannot override the final method from SherlockActivity "

Comment: It's ok, I was missing some package imports. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error "menu cannot be resolved or is not a field" because you are trying to load a resource named "R.menu.StartActivity", but your menu is saved in file "main.xml".  You need to either rename the file to "StartActivity.xml", or change the resource id to "R.menu.main".